# Cannot get PictureBox image to programmatically update

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a C# winform program that loops through images, does some processing, etc. While processing, I want the user to see what image the program is on. I added a picturebox to my program, and I am using this code snippet:

```
pbIDImage.ImageLocation = filepath;
```

If i put this exact line of code in the form constructor (with a hardcoded filepath to test) it displays the image. But then if I put it in my image processing loop where I actually need it, the picturebox never displays the image. Why would it work in the constructor but not in a different method of the program?

Any idea why?

Comment: Show us the relevant "image processing loop"

Comment: You now have completely edited your question so that my answer doesn't fit anymore... I'm sorry!

Comment: @cramopy my edit did not format properly so I removed... shouldn't affect the solution anyway.

Comment: I'll make a wild guess: your "image processing loop" is a blocking process, and nothing on the form updates until it is finishes. In other words: are you processing your images on a background task, or it's just a simple loop in a simple method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the main problem is with the loop.

If the path is OK, the image will load but it doesn't have enough time to be rendered or the UI thread is too busy to reflect changes.

As an evidence you probably see the last image is loaded in the picture box.

As a workaround you can use this code in the loop (That I don't recommend, It's just for test)

```
pbIDImage.ImageLocation = filepath;
pbIDImage.Refresh();
Application.DoEvents();
```

But in general, I think you don't need to show images when you want to change them in a loop or if the change is not too fast, you can use a backgroudworker or task based solution to set the image.

Comment: You're right, the problem was with the loop - it stopped the UI from updating. I had to implement a background worker, actually.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PictureBox.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. As stated in the documentation, either set `ImageLocation` and then call `pictureBoX.Load()`, or directly use the overload that accepts image location like `pictureBox.Load(image_location);`

Note that this behavior is controlled by the [PictureBox.WaitOnLoad Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.waitonload(v=vs.110).aspx), which by default is `false`. So another alternative is to set that property to `true` and then use just `pictureBiox.ImageLocation = ...`. As you see, you have a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

The location variable in the constructor will only be accessed when the imagebox loads the whole control the first time.

This means that you can change the code after generating the variable after creating the imagebox, but this will then obvioulsy not force it to load the image.

You Can download image and save into a variable. Then can the image the control.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The image file paths are already saved into a variable (filepath) and I've tried picturebox.Refresh() and a million other things. How can I force it to reload?

Comment: It reloads the image only by set `pbIDImage.ImageLocation = filepath;` and nothing else is needed.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have tried this, but no image displays :/

Comment: @swinkel It seems it's because using a loop. See the [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33637737/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

The loop was causing the UI to freeze up actually. I implemented a background worker and then the images loaded as expected -- using picturebox.ImageLocation(). That's why in the constructor it loaded fine (loop hadn't started, UI was free) and then when the loop started, the images couldn't load while the processing was happening.